# YouTube video API and Content ID

Tags: youtube-api

Is possible to find out (using the YouTube API) if a video is monetized by the copyright holder with Content ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to determine that from either the Data or Player API.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the prompt reply. That's too bad, as it would work towards easier content discovery I think. API aside, is there any way to find this information other than being the original uploader of the video?